# Brain.js neural network not returning results

Tags: javascript, browser, neural-network, brain.js

I have made an Artificial Neural Network in the browser environment by using Brain.js.
I have attempted to change the structure of the ANN (especially the networks training section) in order to receive an acceptable output.

The Problem is that once run the neural network outputs "**object Object**" .

```
const net = new brain.NeuralNetwork({ hiddenLayers: [] });


const i1 = {
variable1: 32532,
variable2: -3500
}

const i2 = {
variable1: 38295,
variable2: 5763
}

const i3 = {
variable1: 41729,
variable2: 3434
}

const i4 = {
variable1: 45661,
variable2: 3932
}

const i5 = {
variable1: 43789,
variable2: -1872
}

const i6 = {
variable1: 46013,
variable2: 2224
}



const training_set = [
{ input: i1, output: 10.49},
{ input: i2, output: 16.23},
{ input: i3, output: -28.76},
{ input: i4, output: 46.58},
{ input: i5, output: 17.09}
];

net.train(training_set);

alert(net.run(i6));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
alert(JSON.stringify(net.run(i6));
```

You can also print the result to the console for better readability

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(net.run(i6), null, 4));
```

Comment: trying both of your methods they have resulted in the output being "{}" . FYI: you forgot one more closing bracket at the end of your code.

Comment: I tried running your code. The ````net.train```` statement is giving the following output ````{error: NaN, iterations: 20000}````. Maybe that's why the ````net.run```` statement is giving empty response.

Comment: So the training section is the issue. How would you adapt it in order to get the desired output?

Comment: I'm not really sure with your use case and the desired output, you can have a look at https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js#for-training-with-neuralnetwork. I think there is an issue with the input and output values.

Answer (score 0):

brain.NeuralNetwork () takes a hash of numbers between 0 and 1.
The input / output in your training data should contain between 0.00 to 1 .